# pip gives DistributionNotFound error on RHEL

Tags: python, installation, pip

I'm on a work RHEL 5.4 computer with multiple versions of Python installed - definitely 2.4 and 2.7, possibly more. I don't want to fiddle around with uninstalling anything, as it's a standard system setup.

I installed pip using [these instructions](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html) and it appears to have been installed fine. After getting an invalid syntax error, I edited /usr/bin/pip so that it uses python2.7 instead of the default. Now I get the following error message whenever I call pip:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/apollo/env/SDETools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/apollo/env/SDETools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/apollo/env/SDETools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==1.5.6
```

I've seen a few other questions about this error on Stack Overflow, but the answers listed there don't solve it for me. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any other answer, I'll post my workaround for other people. I don't think this is a perfect solution by any means.

I did a search on the entire filesystem for pip and it came up in a couple of locations. One of them was specifically in a *bin* directory that was under the *Python27* directory. Calling that one directly (with the full path) seems to now work.